# Unexpected Results with Boost SerialPort

Tags: c++, boost, qt5

This is my first time using boost and I am certain that there is something simple I am missing.  I am trying to send 3 bytes of data over a serial port.  The three bytes in question are:

day=2;
   month=1;
   year=13;

With the following code, only the first byte is sent.

```
io_service Link;
serial_port serial(Link);
serial.open("/dev/ttyUSB0");
if(serial.is_open())
{
    qDebug() <<"open";
    serial.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
    //send data
    boost::array<int,3> array ={{day,month,year}};
    qDebug()<<serial.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(array,3));
    serial.close();
}
```

The device I am sending to reports back to me (in hex) the values it receives.  It gets the values 0x02,0x00,0x00.  Now tweaking the code as so I can get all three bytes sent to my device:

```
io_service Link;
serial_port serial(Link);
serial.open("/dev/ttyUSB0");
if(serial.is_open())
{
    qDebug() <<"open";
    serial.set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
    //send data
    boost::array<int,1> array ={{day}};
    qDebug()<<serial.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(array,1));
    array={{month}};
    qDebug()<<serial.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(array,1));
    array={{year}};
    qDebug()<<serial.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(array,1));
    serial.close();
}
```

The device Reads: 0x02,0x01,0x0D.  This feels very wrong and I would like to be using these libraries properly.  I suspect that I am not using boost's buffer and array classes correctly, but I really don't know.  Any ideas?

Comment: Define "feels very wrong"?

Comment: sending an array with only one values three times seems to defeat the purpose of having an array.  Why can't the array contain all three items and be sent once?  If I am doing this correctly though I would be happy to erase the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never created a data structure containing the three **bytes** you wanted to send. You only created a data structure containing the three *values* you wanted to send. At no time did you convert those values from the format in which your computer stores them to the wire format in which they were supposed to be sent. So if your code did actually work, it would be entirely by accident.

Of course, your computer doesn't store integers as single bytes. If it did, how could you represent 300? So it's not going to work.

```
boost::array<int,3> array ={{day,month,year}};
qDebug()<<serial.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(array,3));
```

The first line creates a data structure containing the three *values* you want to send. The second line sends those *values* as-is, without ever converting them into the exact stream of bytes that are supposed to be sent over the wire.

If you are expecting a particular stream of bytes to be sent on the serial port, somewhere your code must compose that exact stream of bytes and send it.

Comment: "So if your code did actually work, it would be entirely by accident"  Heh, that sounds about right.  I am going to tweak the code a bit to look into this further.  Thank you.